# How to call self prototype function in javascript object Constructor

Tags: javascript

Why my person doesn't say "Hello" when calling one self method ? How to fix this?

```
var Person = (function () {

  function Person() {
    this.prototype.say();
  }

  Person.prototype.say = function() {
    alert("hello");
  }

  return Person;
})();

var person = new Person();
```

Comment: Don't use the same name for the inner and outer `Person` variables.

Comment: @Barmar Why? This is a pretty common practice.

Comment: because you're getting confused about which `Person`'s prototype you're assigning to. You want to assign to the outer `Person.prototype`, but instead you're assigning to the inner one.

Comment: @Barmar `return Person;` They're the same thing. It's assigned to the prototype of the "inner" `Person` which is then returned and assigned to the "outer" `Person`. They're using an IIFE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call function on the `current` object you shouldn't use `prototype`, just call it(`this.say()`).

```
var Person = (function() {
    function Person() {
        this.say();
    }

    Person.prototype.say = function() {
      alert("hello");
    }
    return Person;
})();

var person = new Person();
```

To learn more about OOP in javascript you can read docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Nice doc and examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for `inheritance` and `prototype chain`

Good notice from @FelixKling

> The object `this` refers to doesn't have a `prototype` property. Only functions have a prototype property.

Comment: I tried on fiddler does not seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/dtxfj1rp/

Comment: @user310291 I've update code

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Can you explain further why yours work and not mine ? I'm relearning javascript OOP.

Comment: @user310291: The object `this` refers to doesn't have a `prototype` property. Only functions have a `prototype` property. The value of that property becomes the prototype of the value of `this`. If you want to learn how prototypes work, I recommend reading https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md .

Comment: @FelixKling good link, am reading it.

Answer (score 1):

isvforall's solution is fine.

The key point is that the 'prototype' defines the functions available on the object you are 'constructing' in the Person() constructor - referred to as 'this.'

The prototype is the shared *base* definitions for all of the objects constructed with Person().  Inside the Person() constructor and the other prototype methods, the instance itself is referenced with 'this'.

See documents such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain for Reference.